# mondrian adapter for bigquery

Tags: mdx, google-bigquery, mondrian

It would be mighty to have a way to query Google's BigQuery with MDX. I believe the natural solution would be a Mondrian adapter.

Is something like this in the works?

The reason I'm asking is because there is a lot of know-how in MDX and an MDX connector would allow us to reuse what we already know.

Furthermore, MDX is ideally suited for OLAP queries. Things like hierarchies and calculating a ratio of one's parent (e.g. % contribution to total) are standardized in MDX but can be solved in 100 different ways in SQL.

Calculating a  Moving Average of the last 3 non empty weeks is still complicated in SQL and easy in MDX. There are many examples.

And lastly, it would allow to analyze data from Google BigQuery with an Excel Pivot or any of the 100+ other existing tools spewing out MDX queries.

Cheers,
Micha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a demo here that is using Mondrian/BigQuery with the Saiku user interface:

http://dev.analytical-labs.com/

This archive contains dependencies that can be used to set up a BigQuery data source in Saiku's embedded Mondrian server (got this from the Saiku twitter feed):

http://t.co/EbtaP95G

Their instructions are here for setting up BigQuery:

https://gist.github.com/4073088

You can download Saiku (with embedded Tomcat and Mondrian) here to run locally for testing:

http://analytical-labs.com/downloads.php

One issue I notice is that the drill-down functionality doesn't work because of the limitations of BigQuery SQL. My guess is that Mondrian devs will have to add some special SQL support for BigQuery to get around this. For example, any fields used in an ORDER BY clause must also be in the SELECT field list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing BigQuery integration with Pentaho's Mondrian. One thing I would point out is that BigQuery is already very fast over massive datasets, so some of Mondrian's advantages may be moot with a BigQuery back end. However, I could imagine that one could use an existing Pentaho analysis tool to explore data. I'd like to know more about the use case.

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific. I am no Mondrian purist, it just happens that it is the main open source MDX implementation and as such, a natural fit for creating an MDX adapter for BigQuery. One more thing: Mondrian is just an interface. It as as fast or slow as the underlying database. This is the reason an integration with BigQuery makes sense: it is mighty fast